# Xcode Auto Layout: Can't resize window

Tags: xcode, constraints, autolayout

What I want to achieve:

```
Custom View 1
   aligned at the top
   fixed height = 20px
   width = window width

Horizontal Split View
   just below the custom view
   width = window width
   height = as large as possible

Custom View 2
   aligned at the bottom
   fixed height = 20px
   width = window width
```

It's a really simple layout: a header and a footer at the top and bottom of the window, and a split view in between with some content to the left and to the right that should resize with the window. However, Apple designed the Auto Layout manager so poorly, I can't seem to get this to work. (I've fumbled around for about three hours now!)

The problem is: As soon as I give the custom views a fixed height, the window height is locked, I can't resize it vertically any more. I'm trying to do this with the following constraints:

```
Custom View 1
    Constraints
    height = 20px

Custom View 2
    height = 20px

Constraints
    Leading horiz space from Custom View 1 to Superview = 0
    Leading horiz space from Custom View 2 to Superview = 0
    Leading horiz space from Split View to Superview = 0
    Trailing horiz space from Custom View 1 to Superview = 0
    Trailing horiz space from Custom View 2 to Superview = 0
    Trailing horiz space from Split View to Superview = 0

    Top vert space between Custom View 1 and Superview = 0
    Vert space between Custom View 1 and Split View = 0
    Vert space between Custom View 2 and Split View = 0
    Bottom vert space between Custom View 2 and Superview = 0
    Top vert space between Custom View 2 and Superview = 344px (!)
```

The last line is added by Xcode, and I can't delete it. Of course, this is responsible for the fixed vertical layout. How can I get rid of it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I finally figured it out.

I had to leave IB's redundant constraint in, but give it a priority of 1. IB had given it a priority of 1000, always overriding my constraint.

Comment: Another solution would be to add the constraint in XCode, but check the box that says "placeholder" - this will remove it at runtime, so your xib will look good, but the constraint won't be fixed in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Every view needs to have enough constraints for the layout system to calculate the position (x and y) and the size (width and height). If the system does not have enough information to calculate these properties, the layout is considered *ambiguous*. Interface Builder in Xcode will not let you create an ambiguous layout, so it will add constraint to ensure a fully constrained layout.

Based on your information, it seems as though subview2 is sufficiently constrained. However, I think maybe you haven't set the height of the view as a constraint. The frame you set for a view is ignored by the layout system. That would introduce ambiguity. **Try adding a height constraint to subview2.**

Comment: OK, I added a constraint to Split View that requires height >= 100. I was able to delete the redundant constraint between the Custom View 2 and the Superview after that. However, IB automatically added a new constraint to Custom View 1 (space to super view bottom = 344), which I can't delete. The window's height is still fixed.

Comment: An inequality constraint (>= 100) will almost never take care of ambiguity issues by itself. Are the top and bottom edges of the splitview pinned to subview 1 and 2?

Comment: Also, do you have height **constraints** on subview1 and subview2? Setting its frame in the size inspector may not be enough. Make sure that you have added a constraint that fixes the height at 20 points.

Comment: Yes, they are. I just recreated these. Strange: If I select the Custom View 1 first and SHIFT-click on the Split View, I can Pin > Vertical Spacing all right. However, if I select the Split View first and then SHIFT-click on the Custom View 1, the menu items for pinning are greyed out.

Comment: Just for the heck of it: try giving the splitview a height of 1000 and set the priority to 500.

Comment: OK, this didn't work, but it lead directly to the solution, see above. Thanks!